# how can I use jinja2 filters from ansible?

Tags: python, jinja2

I am programming with jinjia2. There are lots of jinjia2 filters from ansible I want to use for example `version_compare`. Is there anyway to import the ansible's filters?

Is there any extensions contain filter similar to ansible's `version_compare` filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ansible in your environment, import the filter and register it in the jinja2 environment.

```
from ansible.plugins.test.core import version_compare
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment()
env.filters['version_compare'] = version_compare

template = env.from_string("{{ version|version_compare('2.0', 'ge') }}")
result = template.render(version="1.9")

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Ansible doesn't register `version_compare` as a Jinja2 *filter*.

Example:

```bash
$ ansible -m debug -i localhost, -c local all -a 'msg={{ "1.9" | version_compare("2.0", "ge")  }}' 
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: Could not load \"version_compare\": 'version_compare'. String: {{ \"1.9\" | version_compare(\"2.0\", \"ge\")  }}. Could not load \"version_compare\": 'version_compare'"
}
```

Instead, Ansible adds [`version_compare`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/version_test.html) as a *test* to its Jira2 environment.

---

You can import and register the (core) Ansible filters (and tests) like this:

```
import ansible.plugins.filter.core
import ansible.plugins.test.core
import jinja2

e = jinja2.Environment()

e.filters.update(ansible.plugins.filter.core.FilterModule().filters())
e.tests.update(ansible.plugins.test.core.TestModule().tests())
```

Example usage:

```
t = e.from_string('{{ ["2.0", "1.3", "2.3"] | select("version", "2.0", "ge")'
                  ' | join(",") }}')
print(t.render())
```

yields:

```
'2.0,2.3'
```

NB: `version_compare` is just an alias to `version`

Or:

```
t = e.from_string('{{ s | sha1 }}')
print(t.render(s='Hello World'))
```

yields:

```
0a4d55a8d778e5022fab701977c5d840bbc486d0
```